# JQ Loop over Bash array add elements

Tags: json, bash, jq

I do not seem to be able to find an answer, but have seen enough to know there is likely a better way of doing what I want to do.

Problem: I have a bash array. For each element in the bash array, I want to update a JSON array.

The JSON looks like the below. I am wanting to update the *fruit* array.

```
  "foods": {
    "perishable": {
      "fruit": []
```

I'll get an array of length *n*, for example:

```
fruit_array=("banana" "orange")
```

It should look something like this:

```
  "foods": {
    "perishable": {
      "fruit": [
        { 
          "001": {
            "002": "banana"
          }
        },
        { 
          "001": {
            "002": "orange"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Is there a nice way of doing this? At the moment I am trying the below:

```
#!/bin/bash

fruit_array=("banana" "orange")

for fruit in "${fruit_array[@]}"; do
   jq \
   --arg fruit $fruit \
   '.foods.perishables.fruit += [{"001": {"002": $fruit}}]' \
   template.json > template_with_fruit.json
done
```

This doesn't work for the obvious reason that the template is being re-read, but I have messed around to get it consuming the output of the previous iteration and nothing comes out at the end. I am only able to update the template once.

However, I know this seems a little dodgy and suspect there is a cleaner, more *jq* way.

A previous - aborted - attempt went something like this:

```
jq \
--argjson fruit "$(printf '{"001": {"002": "%s"}}\n' \"${fruit_array[@]}\" | jq -nR '[inputs]')" \
'.foods.perishables.fruit += $fruit' \
```

Which produced a escaped string which I couldn't do anything with, but at least hinted that there might be a neater solution to the standard bash loop.

I am missing something.

Any help would, as always, be appreciated.

Comment: How does the keying work? `"001"` --> Do you want 2 leading `0`? Or must it be 3 long?

Comment: Your JSON template seems to be broken; I'm guessing it should be `{"foods": {"perishable": {"fruit": []}}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JQ can do all that on its own; you don't need a loop or anything.

```
jq '.foods.perishable.fruit += (
  $ARGS.positional
  | map({"001": {"002": .}})
)' template.json --args "${fruit_array[@]}" >template_with_fruit.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass your array as a space delimited string, you can use JQ like so:

```
jq --arg fruits "$fruit_array" \
    '.foods.perishable.fruit |= ($fruits | split(" ") | map({ "001": { "002": . } }))' input
```

---

```json
{
  "foods": {
    "perishable": {
      "fruit": [
        {
          "001": {
            "002": "banana"
          }
        },
        {
          "001": {
            "002": "orange"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In bash, `$fruit_array` is the same as `${fruit_array[0]}` i.e. only the first element of the array. You would want `--arg fruits "${fruit_array[*]}"` here

Answer (score -1):

Create whole json string at once with `printf`:

```
fruit_array=("banana" "orange")
printf -v fruits '{"001": {"002": %s}},' "${fruit_array[@]}"
$ echo $fruits
{"001": {"002": banana}},{"001": {"002": orange}},
```

Then add it to your template removing last comma:

```
$ echo ${fruits%,}
{"001": {"002": banana}},{"001": {"002": orange}}
```

"Numbers" could also be set like this:

```
fruit_array=("1 2 banana" "3 4 orange")
printf '{"%.3d": {"%.3d": %s}},' ${fruit_array[@]}
{"001": {"002": banana}},{"003": {"004": orange}},
```

Comment: That will break for odd fruits like `'fruit with"quote'` -- better to let jq handle all the input. Plus, you're missing quotes around the fruit strings in the temporary JSON.